# Why does changing the "kind" for seaborn replot from "scatter" to "line" make a time series appear incorrectly?

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

```
import seaborn as sns

t=sns.relplot(data=df,x='Grup ve Alt Gruplar',y='GENEL INDEKS',kind='scatter')
t.set_xticklabels(df['Grup ve Alt Gruplar'],rotation=30)

l=sns.relplot(data=df,x='Grup ve Alt Gruplar',y='GENEL INDEKS',kind='line')
l.set_xticklabels(df['Grup ve Alt Gruplar'],rotation=30)
```

The difference between these is only the "kind." The time series of dots looks fine whereas the line output is notably different.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You've set the tick labels manually, but that's not how they are actually plotted (likely). Try removing the tick labels, and it might be clearer to you what's going on. You can see that all the same y and x values are present, they are just scrambled because you've relabeled the x axis.

One thing to highlight is that your x values are not numeric. However, `lineplot` will try to order the x values (alphabetically most likely). `scatter` on the other hand will plot the x values in the order given.